# Facebook post to wall on Android, message only

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

The below code only seems to POST the 'message' and nothing else. Is there something I am missing? (using the Facebook Android SDK)

```
parameters.putString("link", link);
parameters.putString("description", description);
parameters.putString("caption", caption);
parameters.putString("name", name);
parameters.putString("message", msg);

try {
    String response = mFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.toString());
}
```

I am getting lots of warnings but have read this is normal (also, I am getting a warning for 'message' but that still posts:

```
Key caption expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
```

Comment: Also, i'm using the current FB SDK (downloaded last week)

Comment: Any errors you are getting ? any conflict of byteArray , String class cast exception ?

Comment: @sat, yes ClassCastException, the method still posts to the FB wall but does not have the extra parameters such as Caption, Limk, name etc

Comment: @Venky, Yes tried it straight away. It posts to the wall no problem but the problem was that i wanted a more detailed post i.e. with caption, description, links etc

Comment: No, it still does not post anything more than the message.

Comment: @Venky, i didn't see your edited post! Seems to work, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check my edited answer, it will post on the user's wall:

It will show the exception case, but don't bother about it, your post will be succeed.

```
public void postOnWall() {
    try{
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", "Text is lame. Listen up:");
        parameters.putString("name", "Name");
        parameters.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");
        parameters.putString("caption", "Caption");
        parameters.putString("description", "Description");

        String  response = facebook.request("me/feed",parameters,"POST");
        Log.v("response", response);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Comment: this does not work either in allowing me to post Link, Caption etc to the stream

Comment: @Matt One question, You need to Post with or without Dialog??

Comment: Without dialog (please don't tell me you cannot post extra parameters) :)

Comment: @Matt Want to post to your wall or your friend's wall??

Comment: I want to post to my own wall (the user of the app's wall)

Comment: @Venky Hey man.. can you tell me how to make `facebook` object in your code, the one you used for `facebook.request`. I am new to Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 0):

See the below code. It's running code. Try it once.

```
public void postOnWall(String msg) {
    Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
    try {
        String response = facebook.request("me");
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", msg);
        parameters.putString("description", "test test test");
        response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters,
                "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
                response.equals("false")) {
           Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the code i built on. It still only send the message and not the description

Comment: In case of facebook wall message post there is no difference between message and desciption. Message itself is a description of the wall message post(not image post).

Comment: OK, that makes sense but why does Link, Name, Caption not work either?

Comment: Facebook wall message post is similar to comment. It means you are posting a message only. It can't have any caption,name etc like comments.

Comment: So, sorry for my ignorance, how can i post more details posts to a Facebook wall from my app? (it needs to use a dialog?)

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? A dialog checking before posting to the wall or something else you like do.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work with authentication dialog box

```
     private static final String[] PERMISSIONS =
           new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"};


  Facebook authenticatedFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);


   postButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            authenticatedFacebook.authorize(Tests.this, PERMISSIONS,
                    new TestPostListener());
        }
    });


 public class TestPostListener implements DialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
         try {
             Log.d("Tests", "Testing request for 'me'");
             String response = authenticatedFacebook.request("me");
             JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(response);

             Log.d("Tests", "Testing graph API wall post");
             Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
             parameters.putString("message", "Amit Siddhpura");
             parameters.putString("description", "Hi Mr. Amit Siddhpura");
             response = authenticatedFacebook.request("me/feed", parameters, 
                     "POST");
             Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
         } catch (Throwable e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    public void onCancel() {
    }

    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```